# How can I retreive my lost source code on heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I accidentally lost my source code.

I can see my app running on heroku. That does not mean that the code is still there though. It's a python server.

I tried `git clone` and `heroku container:pull web --app`. But it clones an empty repository, even though I am sure I commited my code and pushed it with `heroku container:push web`.

Comment: Yes maybe. In that case how can I retreive the package deployed

Comment: I said the command I used in my problem description. It's heroku container:push web

Answer (score 0):

This is the command to use

```
heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
```